# R data.table get index for the by blocks

Tags: r, data.table

In the `data.table` package there are some available variables like `.N` or`.BY`. Is there also one which holds the index in that group, e.x. starting with 1 in every group, that I could use like `.IDX` in the following command:

```
DT[order(year), indexOfYear := .IDX, by = list(country, sector)]
```

This would be very helpful for working with time panels. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use `indexOfYear := 1:.N`. Though idealy `indexOfYear := .I` should have worked (but it doesn't for some reason I never managed to understand).

Comment: `seq_len(.N)` perhaps?

Comment: `.GRP` is indexing the groups, I want to index the rows in the group. I also thought `.I` should the right choice but it doesn't work. `seq_len(.N)` seems too work, thanks!

Comment: And `1:.N` didn't work for you too? Strange...

Comment: @DavidArenburg, you are right, it works also with `1:.N`. I got as main message that `.I` should work, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## UPDATE: Using `rowid`

The current development version of `data.table` (see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) for how to install) has a newly implemented convenience function for this situation: `rowid` (or `rowidv`).

```
DT[, indexOfYear := rowid(country,sector)]
```

---

Original answer:

As Ananda Mahto and David Arenburg pointed out in a comment above

```
DT[order(year), indexOfYear := seq_len(.N), by = list(country, sector)]
```

does exactly what I was asking for, indexing the rows in each group.